# How to create a simple login in ASP.NET core without database and authorize controller access

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1. How should create a simple ASP.NET Core based login without the use of databases. Lets say instead of using a database, I have the login UserName and Password in the appsettings.json. I could easily access and get the appsettings values. But how should I go about implementing the login functionality and how should I configure services in the startup.cs (in Configure and ConfigureServices).

In Configure() method I have added the `app.UseAuthentication();`

When I login and move to the Controller class which uses the annotation [Authorize] I get the following error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
>   there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be
>   set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or
>   AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext
>   context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Comment: This is actually an interesting question. I don't see any reason why you could not store login information in a text file or even hard code it into your app. It sounds like you want to have it work excactly as the standard auth, but that is made to use with databases. You would need to make your own, which is a longer process. But you can use sqlite, which is just a file on your computer. Check into that first.

Answer (score 14):

Firstly it's not a good idea to store user's credentials into appsettings.json . If you want to implement that for testing purpose , you can use cookie authentication :

[Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

A simple code sample below is for your reference :

1. In the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method, create the Authentication Middleware services with the `AddAuthentication` and `AddCookie` methods:

   ```
   services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddCookie(options =>
           {
               options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
           });
   ```

   And enable middleware in `Configure` :

   ```
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseAuthorization();
   ```
2. You can apply the  `[Authorize]` attribute on protected controllers/actions. When user is not Authenticated , by defalut user will be redirect to LoginPath for cookie authentication . `/Account/Login` action will show username/password textbox to collect user's credential .
3. After user inputs credential and click submit button , the post method will check credential and create cookie :

   ```
   public class AccountController : Controller
   {

       private readonly IOptions<List<UserToLogin>> _users;
       public AccountController (IOptions<List<UserToLogin>> users)
       {

           _users = users;
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserToLogin userToLogin)
       {
           var user = _users.Value.Find(c => c.UserName == userToLogin.UserName && c.Password == userToLogin.Password);

           if (!(user is null))
           {
               var claims = new List<Claim>
               {
                   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,userToLogin.UserName),
                   new Claim("FullName", userToLogin.UserName),
                   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
               };

               var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                   claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

               var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
               {

                   RedirectUri = "/Home/Index",

               };

               await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                   CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                   new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                   authProperties);
           }

           return Redirect("/Accout/Error");
       }
   }
   ```

   UserToLogin.cs :

   ```
   public class UserToLogin
   {
       public string UserName { get; set; }
       public string Password { get; set; }

   }
   ```

   appsettings.json:

   ```
   {
       "Users": [
           {
               "UserName": "xxxxxxxx",
               "Password": "xxxxxxx"            
           },
           {
               "UserName": "xxxxxxxx",
               "Password": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"            
           }       
       ],           
   }
   ```

   And register in ConfigureServices :

   ```
   services.Configure<List<UserToLogin>>(Configuration.GetSection("Users"));
   ```